# Which one (SmootState.js or Angular.js) is proper way/tool to add smooth transition effects between pages of a classical website?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, smoothstate.js

I have a classical multi-page website. Transitions between pages is hard-way, e.g. almost every page is loaded fully via anchors without using javascript.

I want to get smooth transition effects between pages with minimum effort. I have read that Angular is powerful but I don't want to rebuild my current structure. Is that easy with Angular, or should I use smoothState or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a classical multi-page website, you should go for smoothState JS. Angular is a full javascript framework which is not intended for just the animations you want to use. It's too much for your classical website.

Good luck!

https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js